# Связь контроллера с видом

Tags: mvc, php

В общем проблема состоит в том, чтобы мой контроллер понял, какая именно кнопка была нажата, кнопки формируются во View в цикле, из бд вытаскивается строки с вопросами и под каждым вопросом форма и кнопка для ответа, так вот мой контроллер не может определить, какая именно кнопка была нажата, если не дать имя каждой кнопке по идентификатору вопроса, но мне кажется, это не правильный вариант. Как решить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Измените контроллер так, чтобы **для каждого ответа** генерировалась форма с кнопкой:

```
<form action="..." method="post" >
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="..." />
  <input type="submit" value="Ответить" />
</form>
```

Тогда выбранный ответ можно будет идентифицировать по уникальному $_POST['answer_id'].

Answer (score 0):

Обычно выбор делается не кнопками, а radio, если хотите 5 кнопок - делайте 5 форм и указывайте удобные для вас параметры.

Comment: Можно чуть поподробнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать всем кнопкам одинаковые имена, а значения разные, как вариант. Ну, а потом

```
buttonvalue = request.getparameter(buttonName);
if (buttonValue == "value") {...}
```